An 80s / 90s teen comedy movie
I'm looking for a 80s/90s comedy movie that featured two young men with superhuman features and abilities as its protagonists. They were chilling, wandering around the streets. They were very close, best friends I think. Unfortunately I can't remember much about their physical appearance. They were white, probably in their 20s or early 30s, average size. Nothing else. 
After that scene I missed about 20-30 minutes of the movie. They each had a microchip in their brains or behind their ears. It was either planted by some guys or they had planted it by themselves. With this electronic chip they gained some superhuman features. E.g. they could easily speak many languages fluently that they didn't know until that day. They could fight like an expert, applying many fighting styles. They were much stronger, faster and smarter than they were before.
They were surprised to these abilities and used this to flirt with girls. Some girls were chatting amongst each other and saw the guys. Our heroes impressed the girls with their superhuman abilities and the girls were shocked. 
There were some bad guys after these chips and the protagonists tried to escape from them. Also there were some other guys with white labcoats like scientists but I can't remember if they produced these chips or not. 
Some other details: 
Possible release year: Between 1980 - 1997
Genre: Comedy, Sci-fi
Country of Origin: USA, Canada or Western Europe

Although it's more recent, some of these story elements match up with Agent Cody Banks 2: Destination London, although the microchips were 'bad' in this movie.

@Robotnik Thanks for the effort but that’s not the movie i’m looking for..
